# Is there any order of execution for bottle's before_request hooks?

Tags: python, bottle

Let say a bottle app has multile `before_request` hooks. Is there an order of execution for these hooks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Hooks are executed (triggered) by the order of their definitions in the code base.

```
def add_hook(self, name, func): 
    if name in self.__hook_reversed:
        self._hooks[name].insert(0, func)        
    else:
        self._hooks[name].append(func)
def trigger_hook(self, __name, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Trigger a hook and return a list of results. """
    return [hook(*args, **kwargs) for hook in self._hooks[__name][:]]
```